# Kotlin array function asList() unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a code:

```
fun loadSounds(): List<String> {
    try {
      val soundNames = assets.list(SOUNDS_FOLDER)!!
      Log.d (TAG, "Found ${soundNames.size} sounds")
      return soundNames.asList()
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Could not list assets", e)
      return emptyList()
    }
  }
```

I couldn't compile it, because of error:

```
Unresolved reference: asList
```

How can I convert array (array<(out) string!>) to list? And what does array<(out) string!> mean?

**Update:** I have a promblems with asList(), toList() and split(), they are unresolved references.

Comment: After your edit, the error doesn't match the code anymore. Could you please update the error? This code works fine when I try locally with a mocked Java AssetsManager.
Is this really the code you're using?

Comment: Unresolved reference: asList

Comment: Does this just appear in the IDE, or also when you build from command line? It might be because the Kotlin stdlib is not properly added, but I would be surprised since the Kotlin Gradle plugin includes it by default since Kotlin 1.4.

Comment: I don't know how to build from command line, so, yes, in the IDE (Android, not Intellij IDEA). I have in my build.gradle:
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
   ...
}

Comment: now I have "unresolved reference split" error for code: val name = assetPath.split("/"). where the assetPath is String. something wrong is going on, but i dont understand what. I create a new project and still have this error

Comment: Definitely looks like you're missing stdlib functions. I tried to create a new project as well in Android Studio, and it works fine (I have the same line in Gradle defining the stdlib). Maybe `File > invalidate caches/restart` could help the IDE? You can also try to run `./gradlew build` to test this on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason was not in checking for the nullability, but in the project settings, something was broken (maybe stdlib including or something else). I copy my code and paste it in another empty project, rename it and everething is fine now.

Answer (score 3):

> what does array<(out) string!> mean?

This declaration has a bunch of components to unpack:

- `Array` is the base raw type
- `String` is the the type argument of `Array`, which in this case is the element type of the array
- The exclamation mark on `String!` shows that it is a [*platform type*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types). This means that this comes from Java and Kotlin doesn't know the nullability of these Strings. Basically, it can't tell you whether the arrays contains nulls or not. When in doubt like this, Kotlin doesn't force you to check the nullability, for convenience.
- the `out` modifier on the generic type parameter shows that the array may contain subtypes of `String`, so you should not be able to update elements in it in theory (you should only be able to get values "out" of the array, and store them in `String` variables). Kotlin puts parentheses around the `(out)` because it's inferred from Java (nothing is certain). So in practice you might not be restricted like this, and you should still be able to assign the array to a variable of type `Array<String>`, and thus insert stuff in it.

In short, `Array<(out) String!>` means "Java array of Strings (or a subtype of String) which are nullable or not".

---

Now, I'm not very well versed in Android APIs, but it seems that the `assets.list()` function you're calling is [this one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager#list(java.lang.String)).

This method returns a nullable array `Array<out String!>?`, so you can't call methods directly on it without checking for the nullability of the array itself. Either use a safe call with `?` or check for null before returning:

```kotlin
return soundNames?.toList() // you have to make your return type nullable in this case
```

Or:

```kotlin
return soundNames?.toList() ?: error("Null assets array")
```

---

#### EDIT

After the edit in the question, it seems that the nullability is now already handled via `!!` operator, and that the problematic method is now `asList()` instead of `toList()`. So this is a different story.

Comment: Checking the nullability doesn't do a trick, I have the same error that I mentioned. I have minSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 30

Comment: @DmitryFedorov could you please add types to your declaration in your code? It would help answer the question. I don't know what the type of `assets.list()` is, so it's hard to tell how to help here. Please add `val soundNames: TYPE_HERE = assets.list()`, in a way that compiles. Also, what's the type of `assets`?

Comment: val soundNames: Array<(out) String!> and assets: private final val assets: AssetManager. And I was wrong, missing not soundNames.toList() function, but soundNames.asList() . And correct note was: val soundNames = assets.list(SOUNDS_FOLDER)!!  . I.e. with "!!"

Comment: @DmitryFedorov The `!!` operatory simply throws an exception if `list()` returns null, just like the option I mentioned with the safe call `?` + elvis `?:` + `error()`. It's usually better to throw a more specific error like `assets.list(..) ?: error("some specific text")`

Comment: @DmitryFedorov you cannot write `Array<(out) String!>` in the code, this wouldn't compile. You probably have to write something like `Array<String>` instead, or `Array<out String>`. Also, why do you need `asList()`? Isn't `toList()` sufficient for you? `asList()` is only defined on `Array<out String>`, not on `Array<String>`, so depending on which type you choose for your variable, you'll have access to `asList` or not.

Comment: It's missing asList() and toList() too. I tried cast like this: val soundNames = assets.list (SOUNDS_FOLDER)!! as Array<String> . But still don't have neither asList() nor toList()

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code.

```
fun loadSounds(): List<String>? {
    try {
        val soundNames = assets.list ("")
        Log.d (TAG, "Found ${soundNames?.size} sounds")
        return soundNames?.toList()
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not list assets", e)
        return emptyList()
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I have the same error that I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I solved it.

Check the "gradle : project" and Check if it's more than kotlin 1.5 version.